# Whats the right way to separate model and logic

Tags: java, maven, jpa, annotations

Hi I'm setting up a new project and was struggeling with Java Annotations.
Are they related to Logic / API or Model

### In Detail:

I have a started a multi maven module for example:

- project-parent
- project-model
- project-persist
- project-logic1

I separated model from every other module simple POJOs with JPA. 
To use them with different frontends or REST etc. 
Now I wanna use annotations from **project-logic1** in the model.

Now i'm confused with the seperation.

- Should I make an own API module (**project-API**) for this and similar annotation / interfaces
- Should I simply add the annotation in the **project-model**
- Should I add the dependency of **project-logic1** into the **project-model** POM

I think the first one is correctly but I'm not sure.

Comment: That's a matter of opinion

Comment: There is no "right" way! There are many different ways, all with advantages and disadvantages and totally subject to the precise context

Comment: I suppose it depends on how **you** feel the most comfortable to work with.

Comment: your question is too broad for stack overflow ...

Comment: Sorry ~ I though very simple maybe the question should be "Are Annotations Model or Logic" or something .... sometime I should just wait and talk to my rubber duck, before I post things on Stackoverflow ~
Now im still struggeling with a clean seperation of the project. And make ppls mad ~

Comment: As learning for me, this question should be better posted in "Software Engineering Stack Exchange" right? Or whats an appropriated place for asking such questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you shouldn't use your model objects (with the JPA annotations) as DTO in your project.
You should have your model within the logic project, so DB related items are un the same place, and you create and API project with only POJO, not related to your DB, so you can use this API for REST services' answers and keep your implementation hidden.

Comment: I am not sure if the question is about "JPA annotations" but rather custom annotations defined in the project-logic1

Comment: But when I use DB related Items looks almost like the API POJO Objects, then I have duplicated code :S

Comment: Yes, that's right, but when it comes to API, you can't really avoid that, as your duplicated code is boiler plate code (getters and setters).Though, doing so will help make your code easier to maintain. Looking to avoid duplicated code is good, but sometimes, to add abstractions and open your objects to the outside, you might need to duplicate a bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have common code, I would suggest to wrap it into a dedicated module, so I would agree with your "API"-Approach (although the label "API" might be too much here). 
Do not cross-reference your modules, dependencies must always go one way. And: Never repeat yourself, so c/p-ing your annotations is fundamentally wrong ;)

Comment: I would never copy and paste things or reapeat myself. Therfore I'm asking where annotations and co should be located.

Comment: some common module "common-<purpose>" might be a good call then